# axios.post is not sending data in body

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

i am sending form data via axios.post from react frontend to nodejs backend but i am getting undefined in the req.body in the backend, my backend is working from postman

my frontend

```
import React,{useState} from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function Compose(){

    const [inputTitle, setInputTitle] = useState("");
    const [inputBody, setInputBody] = useState("");
    function handleSubmit(event){
        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/compose',{
            title:  inputTitle,
            content: inputBody
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h1>Compose</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="postTitle" className="form-label">Title :</label>
                    <input type="text" name="postTitle" className="form-control" onChange={(event)=>{setInputTitle(event.target.value)}} />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="postBody" className="form-label">Post :</label>
                    <textarea  className="form-control" name="postBody" rows="4" onChange={(event)=>{setInputBody(event.target.value)}}></textarea>
                </div>
                <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Publish</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Compose;
```

my backend

```
app.post("/compose", function(req,res){
  console.log(req.body.title);
  let newPost = new Post({
    title:req.body.title,
    content:req.body.content
  });

  newPost.save(function(err,result){
    if (err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    else{
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
})
```

i tried sending axios.post in data like this

```
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/compose',{data:{
            title:  inputTitle,
            content: inputBody
        }})
```

but it didn't work

Comment: is your `handleSubmit` function working properly? axios doesn't seem to have any issue. try adding a catch to `axios.post` maybe you'll find something.

Comment: Did you parse the body on the backend?

Comment: yes, @Konrad using body-parser

Comment: yes, Mojo-Allmighty handleSubmit is working and backend is saving empty data with to database

Comment: where is your nodejs entry file ? Add `app.use(express.json());` before router.